# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined in NV D3 StackedLine

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have put together a stacked line chart using nvd3's helpful pre-packaged charts.

I get the chart doing the majority of the functionality fine, but whenever I click on a specific series the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined', and the chart does not resize to only display the series.

For an example of correct functionality: http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

I've checked against the most common errors, including differently sized series, and it's none of those.

The code I'm using for generating the chart is:

```
function stackedChart(data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                      .margin({right: 100})
                      .x(function(d) { return d[0] })   
                      .y(function(d) { return d[1] })  
                      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                      .duration(500)    
                      .showControls(true)      
                      .clipEdge(true);


        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

        chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

        d3.select('#stackedChart svg')
          .datum(data)
          .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });

}

stackedChart(a);
```

with the data found in the jsfiddle with a live example of the error: https://jsfiddle.net/0yxr15ut/5/

Comment: If you are using two different charts at the same time using area chart, make sure the value for your Y-axis exists in the dataset for both charts.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same thing, I run checks to see matching labels for each value in the datasets.

Comment: @JosueIbarra: could you elaborate?

Comment: What happened was that I had an angularjs app that made use of the the library `angularjs-nvd3-directives` I updated the model without calling $scope.$apply() and it messed up the chart. Enclosing the model update in $apply() worked for me. Unrelated to this, I had another issue with the library and rewrote everything to use [Angular-nvD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) since it has better support and features.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addresses here:
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1093
A workaround is available for this issue although not sure about the side effects.
Add the following check in the scatter y function in your nv.d3.js

```
.y(function(d) {
              if (d.display !== undefined) { return d.display.y + d.display.y0; }
              else return 0
            })
```

I have made a for repository which has this change which you can use.
https://github.com/nishantk92/nvd3.git